# How can you add an email within a URL in multi-step form to a hidden email form field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, webflow

I've created a multi-step form in Webflow containing two pages:

Step 1: /get-started
Step 2: /get-started-final

For get-started, I've added the following code before the  tag

```
<script>
Webflow.push(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      location.href = 'https://websitedomain.com/get-started-final?email=' + $('#emailget').val();
    }, 100);
  });
});
</script>
```

This page is the first page of the form input and only asks for name and email.

Now for **Get Started Final**, I ask for 4 additional fields, but I also want to pull the email from the URL and add it to a hidden form field in Get Started Final.

```
<script>
function getParameterByName(url) {
    if(!url) url = window.location.href;
    var matches = url.match(/[\?|\&]?email=(.+)/)
    if (!matches[1]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(matches[1]);
}
Webflow.push(function() {
  $('#emailget').val(getParameterByName('email'));
});
</script>
```

I have a non-hidden email input in 'Get-Started-Final' to test if the code works, but it doesn't populate the input with the email.

The email input has an ID of emailget. After I validate that it does grab the email, I'll switch it to hidden.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are applying the regex match on the `url` argument, in the function `getParameterByName`, instead of the actual URL itself, and an error will occur at `if (!matches[1])` because there is no matches:

```
function getParameterByName(url) {
    if(!url) url = window.location.href;
    var matches = url.match(/[\?|\&]?email=(.+)/)
    if (!matches[1]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(matches[1]);
}
```

I'm guessing you simply want to get a specific parameter in the URL, so your function could be as simple as this:

```
const getParameterByKey = key => new URLSearchParams(location.search).get(key);
```

Full code:

```
<script>
const getUrlParameterFor = key => new URLSearchParams(location.search).get(key);
Webflow.push(function() {
  $('#emailget').val(getUrlParameterFor('email'));
});
</script>
```